# Getting values of xml based file for J2ME coding

Tags: xml, java-me

I have send a hit a site as below

http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=SECRETAPIKEY&mnc=608&mcc=310&lac=69&cellid=41663

from this i get some info which gives me latitude and longitudes of particular mobile device

Then i get a xml based file 
But now how do i get or extract the values of latitudes and longitudes from the xml structred file for j2me coding ?

Comment: ok ... then i need to google it now i guess for parsing

Comment: I guess you can search here on SO too [java-me]+parsing xml

Comment: For example, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9907285/1284073