# how to remove HTML tags from parsed text?

Tags: html, blackberry, java-me

I'm developing for BlackBerry platform, OS 5,6,7

I have parsed an RSS feed in a String then listed it into a ListField,

but the parsed String is full of HTML tags like:

`"<div id="cke_pastebin" style="text-align: justify; ">"`

and other HTML and CSS tags.

What is the best method to remove the HTML tags from the String?

I used `subString` method but it won't work perfect.

Comment: How did you parse your RSS feed? Manually? Sax? Dom?

Comment: I would go with SAX as I said in this this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890222/need-some-help-in-parsing-this-xml-in-j2me-platform/9907285#9907285

Comment: so SAX parser can remove HTML elements and tags from parsed XML ?

Comment: You can already achieve what you want with DOM and a recursive method to walk the tree and extract only the text. I suggested SAX because I think it is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. Let the browser do the work for you.

```
var html = "<p>Hello, <b>World</b>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
alert(div.innerText); // Hello, World
```

Comment: hey Mr Marc B. i'm developing for BlackBerry as you can see from the quastion tags. Thank you